# Change all span-tags into label-tags with Javascript?

Tags: javascript

what I want to do: call an unload-function to change

```
<span>some content</span>
```

into

```
<label>some content</label>
```

Is it possible to change a span-tag into a label-tag with javascript? If it is possible how can I do that?

Thnx,

... doro

Comment: so i can add an onfocus which should work in opera as well, but doesnt on spans ... I need that b/c a user can change the content b/c contenteditable is set to true, but if the change wasn't exactly right it needs to be reversed to old state ... oh, yeah, I surely could use label right in the first place, but the page is built dynamically and I'll never know what I get, so when I have a span with contenteditable=true, I now know how to change them to labels where onfocus supposedly works even with opera ... well, so much I was hoping :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And if you're using jQuery you can use replaceWith()

```
jQuery.each($("span"), function() {
  $(this).replaceWith("<label>" + $(this).text() + "</label>");
});
```

More information at: http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/replaceWith

Answer (score 4):

First you need to gain a reference to the SPAN element, then you can go about replacing it with a new element:

HTML:

```
<span id="something">Content</span>
```

JavaScript:

```
var span = document.getElementById('something');
var label = document.createElement('label');
label.innerHTML = span.innerHTML;
span.parentNode.replaceChild( label, span );
```

Comment: but i had to give every span i want to convert the id "something", right?

Comment: you won't want to give the same id to multiple elements. But you could give all spans you want to change a class name. Then do `document.getElementsByClassName("changeSpan");`, and loop through them and run the code by J-P on each element.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `replace()`. More info [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)

I'm not very good at RegExp, so I can't tell you exactly what to write, but something along the lines of:

```
var divHTML = getElementById("myDiv"); //The div which contains your spans
divHTML.innerHTML.replace(/<span>/gi, "<label>");
divHTML.innerHTML.replace(/<\/span>/gi, "</label>");
```

Please don't bust me on this, though :p

**edit:** If you want to maintain class names, ids and such, you simply leave out the right-angle-bracket:

```
divHTML.innerHTML.replace(/<span/gi, "<label");
```

This will turn `<span id="mySpan" class="spans">` into `<label id="mySpan" class="spans">`

Answer (score 2):

(Using jQuery) If you need to maintain the classes between the conversion:

```
$("span").each(function(){
    so_classes = $(this).attr("class");
    so_value = $(this).html();
    so_newLabel = $("<label></label>").html(so_value);
    if (so_classes.length > 0) {
        $(so_newLabel).attr("class",so_classes);
    }
    $(this).replaceWith(so_newLabel);
});
```

Converts this

```
<span>Hello World</span>
<span class="bigger"><strong>Hello World!</strong></span>
<span class="big blue">Hello, <em>World</em>.</span>
```

Into this

```
<label>Hello World</label>
<label class="bigger"><strong>Hello World!</strong></label>
<label class="big blue">Hello, <em>World</em>.</label>
```

Comment: Copying/modifying the so_classes line, you can maintain id values too.

Answer (score 1):

You can also select the specific element you want and use outerHTML.

```
elementToReplace.outerHTML.replace(/(?<=<(?:\/)?)span(?:.*?)(?<!>)/gi, 'label')
```

Or replace all for a specific selector.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.label').forEach(e => e.outerHTML = e.outerHTML.replace(/(?<=<(?:\/)?)span(?:.*?)(?<!>)/gi, 'label'));
```

This regex matches only the tag name so you don't have to add anything extra to the replacement string.

Example: https://regex101.com/r/VS9sP6/1

Answer (score 0):

```
document.body.innerHTML = 
    document.body.innerHTML.
         replace(/<span>/g, '<label>').
         replace(/<\/span>/g, '</label>');
```