# Change tag using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to know how can I change a tag with pure javascript like that

```
    <span>some text</span>
```

I want to change it to that

```
  <div>some text</div>
```

I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Are you wanting your answer in pure Javascript or are you using jQuery?

Comment: Also, do you want to replace all instances of <span> tags or just a specific one?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170970/change-all-span-tags-into-label-tags-with-javascript

Comment: Take a look here, it's quite easy to do with jQuery (if you are able to use it) -> http://jsfiddle.net/JHmaV/

Comment: I want to know with pure javascript and I want a specific one thank you! and I didnt tried anything because Ihave no clue how to do it.

Comment: It's a legitimate question. Why the down votes ?

Answer (score 92):

You can't change the type of an element like that, instead you have to create a new element and move the contents into it. Example:

```
var e = document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0];

var d = document.createElement('div');
d.innerHTML = e.innerHTML;

e.parentNode.replaceChild(d, e);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/bhnWR/

Comment: @Guffa: `e.parentNode.replaceChild(d, e);` but +1 ;-)

Comment: @IHateLazy @bdkopen Why is `insertBeofre()` and `removeChild()` wrong?

Comment: I realize the original question didn't ask for this, but this doesn't take any attributes with it. In other words, if the original HTML was `<span class="foo">bar</span>`, it would still make the resulting HTML `<div>bar</div>`.

Comment: 1 line version: `document.querySelectorAll(".yuRUbf a").forEach(e=>e.parentNode.replaceChild(Object.assign(document.createElement("div"),{innerHTML:e.innerHTML}),e));`

Comment: Instead of `replaceChild` on the parent, I prefer to `replaceWith` directly

Comment: @Cloud: The `replaceWIth` method is a more recent addition than `replaceChild`. Check the support information to see if it exists in the browser versions that you need to support.

Comment: Ah makes sense, thankfully for my uses I can assume a relatively recent browser version

Answer (score 6):

Just written a jQuery plugin for this.

```
(function( $ ) {
  $.fn.replaceTag = function(newTag) {
    var originalElement = this[0]
    , originalTag = originalElement.tagName
    , startRX = new RegExp('^<'+originalTag, 'i')
    , endRX = new RegExp(originalTag+'>$', 'i')
    , startSubst = '<'+newTag
    , endSubst = newTag+'>'
    , newHTML = originalElement.outerHTML
    .replace(startRX, startSubst)
    .replace(endRX, endSubst);
    this.replaceWith(newHTML);
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Usage:

```
$('div#toChange').replaceTag('span')
```

The biggest advantage of this method is that id preserves all the attributes of the original element.

Comment: He explicitly asked for a 'pure javascript' answer.

Answer (score 0):

If jquery is acceptable use replaceWith.

```
$('span').each(function() {
    
  $(this).replaceWith($('<div>' + this.innerHTML + '</div>'));
 
});
```

Here is a JSFIDDLE working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SJuYh/)

Comment: alternatively without jquery and in a slightly different case: http://jsfiddle.net/CvRq2/

Comment: He asked for a pure javascript answer.

Answer (score -2):

Assumption: The span you want to replace is wrapped in a div with id "foo"

In pure javascript you could do something like:

```
 var original_html = document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML;

 original_html = original_html.replace("<span>", "<div>");

 original_html = original_html.replace(new RegExp("</span>"+$), "</div">)
 document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML=original_html;
```

If however you can not necessarily expect the span to be tightly wrapped by an element you can consistently get (by id or otherwise), the javascript becomes fairly complex. In either case, the real answer here is: use jQuery.

Comment: This approach would have all sorts of side effects. Also, using a regexp is expensive and in this case a terrible use case.

Comment: Terrible use case how? Side effects which? You should elaborate as to not waste time when people could read something useful.

Answer (score -3):

If using jquery

```
 Var spantxt = $('span').text();
 $('body').append('<div>'+spantext+'</div');
```

Note this would only work if there was only one span, use an id selector otherwise

Comment: @bluejayke https://jsfiddle.net/barney/kDjuf/

Answer (score -3):

You can't do it. 
What you want to do is to take content of your `span`,
then delete it and create new `div` and fill it with previous content.