# javascript - replace text with tags

Tags: javascript, text, replace

i do not know much about javascript searched long, but didn't get the reslut i need.

i want to replace  on page load  this

```
<p>---SOMERANDOMTEXT:::</p>
```

with

```
<strong>SOMERANDOMTEXT</strong>
```

played with this an many other snippets..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        function myscript() {
            input = '---';
            output='New Text';
            document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(input,output);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: So anything between "---" and ":::"?

Comment: Where does `<p>---SOMERANDOMTEXT:::</p>` come from? Do you produce that yourself? If so, there's a better way of doing what you're doing.

Comment: You don't need to wrap a function declaration like that in a `window.onload`.

Comment: Take a look in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13389751/change-tag-using-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the fast and fool proof way of replacing `<p>` tags with `<strong>` tags:

```
var ps = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
for (var i = ps.length; i--;) {
    var strong = document.createElement('strong'),
        p = ps[i];

    while (p.firstChild) {
        strong.appendChild(p.firstChild);
    }

    p.parentNode.insertBefore(strong, p);
    p.parentNode.removeChild(p);
}
```

If you need to change the text accordingly, place something like that in the `while` loop:

```
if (p.firstChild.nodeType === 3) {
    p.firstChild.nodeValue = p.firstChild.nodeValue.replace(/[-:]{3}/g, '');
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/5m9Qm/1/

Comment: @oGeez Added the workaround which will work for all direct children of each `<p>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call your `myscript` function like this -

```
window.onload = function() {
  myscript();
}
function myscript() {
    var input = '---';
    var output='New Text';
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(input,output);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring a function `myscript` but never invoking it. Try this (untested) code:

```
<script>
window.onload = function(){
    var p = document.querySelector('p');
    var strong = document.createElement('strong');
    strong.innerHTML = 'replaced';
    p.parentNode.replaceChild(strong,p);

})
</script>
```

Note this requires modern browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex.

Try:

```
output = document.body.innerText.replace(/[-:]{3}/g, '');
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/<p>---.*:::<\/p>/, '<strong>' + output + '</strong>');
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AM7bv/4/)

Comment: Or `/<p>---.*:::<\/p>/` so that you **replace** the paragraph, rather than append to it.

Comment: @oGeez Actually i havent cleared yet what OP wants to do, but good point. I edited

Comment: This solution will remove *all* bound events in body + it is tremendously slow.

Comment: Also, I've just realised, this would be you'd need to specify a new value, which defeats the idea (AFAIA).