# convert one element into a like element ala Div -> Span and retain all attributes

Tags: jquery

Say I have an element like so:

```
<div id="color1" foo="test" class="yes">Hello</div>
```

I want to turn it into:

```
<span id="color1" foo="test" class="yes">Hello</span>
```

I thought to use wrap/unwrap, but not quite getting what I need.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14645806/get-all-attributes-of-an-element-using-jquery

Comment: Thanks Matt, that isn't exactly what I am looking for. I don't necessarily want the attributes. I just want to create a new element and make sure the integrity of the attributes are intact. thanks though.

Comment: @Ker cause I don't have control of the initial elements. That is why I need to convert them on the fly.

Comment: what exactly does "make sure the integrity of the attributes are intact" mean? Either you want to copy the attributes or you don't, you can't  create a new element and magically have the same attributes without copying them ?

Comment: I agree with @adeneo. Also, an attribute like `id` can't be duplicated on a page. No two elements can have the same `id`, so what should be done in this situation?

Comment: what exactly do you want to do with the new element? replace original? Comments made make it very confusing since other answer has all the important attribute information

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to change an element type using jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584098/how-to-change-an-element-type-using-jquery)

Comment: Here's another way to do it -> **http://jsfiddle.net/p479G/**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change tag using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13389751/change-tag-using-javascript)

Comment: @adeneo - clever boy you are! lol. That is nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit, removed `g` `modifier` from `RegExp`

```
var _s = $("div#color1").clone()[0].outerHTML.replace(/div/, "span");
$("div#color1").replaceWith(_s);
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/E53tN/