# How to replace an <img/> HTML tag using JavaScript .replace() method

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `img` tag like

```
<img src="Mesothelioma_image_1.jpg"/>
```

I want to replace this tag with something like

```
<amp-img class="blog-image" src="Mesothelioma_image_1.jpg" width="50" height= "20" layout="responsive"></amp-img>
```

By keeping the same `src` attribute value.

Comment: Is the img tag inside another html tag with a known id?

Comment: [`replaceWith`](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/)

Comment: Is this the same problem as the one on this thread maybe? https://stackoverflow.com/q/13389751/6124074

Comment: Hopefully you are doing this in the backend and not on the frontend.

Comment: @epascarello this could be done in the frontend without a problem. Angular and other frameworks does this successfully.

Comment: You can achieve it in many ways Either by Jquery or you can create a directive for it which can be attribute type and will replace the complete tag on its call

Answer (score 1):

You can use `querySelector()` to find the image. It would be easier if the image contains an id attribute.

Then, use `createElement()` to create the dom element by name `amp-img`.

Use `setAttribute()` to assign attributes to the new elements such as class, src, width, erc.

Use `insertBefore()` to add new element to the page and `remove()` to remove the old image element.

**NOTE:** I am selecting the old image with its `src`, please change it as per your need.

```js
var oldImage = document.querySelector('img[src="Mesothelioma_image_1.jpg"]');

var newImage = document.createElement('amp-img');
newImage.setAttribute("class","blog-image");
newImage.setAttribute("src", oldImage.getAttribute('src'));
newImage.setAttribute("width","50");
newImage.setAttribute("height","20");
newImage.setAttribute("layout","responsive");
oldImage.parentNode.insertBefore(newImage, oldImage);
oldImage.parentNode.removeChild(oldImage);

console.log(document.querySelector('amp-img[src="Mesothelioma_image_1.jpg"]')); // to find the appended new image
```

```html
<img src="Mesothelioma_image_1.jpg"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see below code.

You will need to access img using parent class or Id.
i have did this work on a link click event, You can do this on document.ready or any other event as well.

```js
jQuery('.clickMe').click(
function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var img = jQuery('.parent img').attr('src');  
    var newhtml='<amp-img class="blog-image" src="'+img+'" width="50" height= "20" layout="responsive"></amp-img>';
  // console.log('IMG: '+ img);
  
  jQuery('.parent').html(newhtml);
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <img src="https://mosthdwallpapers.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Pakistan-Flag-Image-Free-Download.jpg"/>
</div>
<a class="clickMe" href="#">Click Me </a>

<amp-img class="blog-image" src="Mesothelioma_image_1.jpg" width="50" height= "20" layout="responsive"></amp-img>
```

Comment: He does not need to access it using a parent class or id. Look at my comment on the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45057562/how-to-replace-an-img-html-tag-using-js-replace-method#comment77088423_45057562).

Comment: remove `.parent` from this line  `var img = jQuery('.parent img').attr('src');  `