# Replace a certain set of elements in a DOM at once

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Assume I have a DOM tree represented by this html.

```html
<div id="root">
  <div>
    <p>hoge</p>
    <span>fuga</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>piyo</span>
    <div>
      <span>foobar</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If I want to replace all the `<span>`s by `<button>`, how could I achieve it?

```
const replaceElements = () => {
  const page = document.getElementById("root")
  const elements = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
  elements.forEach(item => ???)
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change tag using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13389751/change-tag-using-javascript)

Comment: I wanted to replace all the tag at once, so it'd be different from the question. (Though the answer was just using a loop.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It keeps getting the first `span` and converting it to a button until there are no more `span`s by replacing the element with button tags around the span's innerHTML. Check out the snippet. (tested in Chrome 76)

```
const replaceElements = () => {
  const elements = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
  while (elements.length > 0) {
  const item = elements[0];
    item.outerHTML = '<button>' + item.innerHTML + '</button>';
  }
}
```

```js
const replaceElements = () => {
  const elements = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
  while (elements.length > 0) {
  const item = elements[0];
    item.outerHTML = '<button>' + item.innerHTML + '</button>';
  }
}
replaceElements();
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <div>
    <p>hoge</p>
    <span>fuga</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>piyo</span>
    <div>
      <span>foobar</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have corrected the typos, thank you. Also using while seems interesting and easy to underestand for this purpose :)

Answer (score 1):

The way that you have it set up you will need to assign the innerHTML of the spans into new button elements for each span found. Try this:

```
const replaceElements = () =>{
    //get all span elements
    var spans = document.querySelectorAll("span");

    // loop over all of them
    for(let i=0; i<spans.length;i++){

        // create the new btn and get the parent
        var newBtn = document.createElement("button"),
        parent = spans[i].parentNode;

        // set innerhtml of btn
        newBtn.innerHTML = spans[i].innerHTML;

        // replace the node in the parent container
        parent.replaceChild(newBtn,spans[i]);
    }
}
```