# Jquery to change outerhtml

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a span in the form of:

```
<span eid="4" etype="dc" class="remove-absolute" style="display: block">
  <div>
    <span>ttttttt</span>
    <p>ttttttt</p>
  </div>
</span>
```

I want to change the outerHTML(from span to div), so it looks like:

```
<**div** eid="4" etype="dc" class="remove-absolute" style="display: block">
  <div>
    <span>ttttttt</span>
    <p>ttttttt</p>
  </div>
</**div**>
```

I checked other solutions, I tried replaceWith, but it doesn't work.

I tried:

```
$('[etype="dc"]')[0].replaceWith("abcd");  


$('[etype="dc"]')[0].outerHTML => is still unchanged. canI get some help?
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change tag using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13389751/change-tag-using-javascript)

Comment: Not fully..   I tried $(this).replaceWith($('<div>' + this.innerHTML + '</div>')), but it doesn't keep the attribute of the tag. I want to keep eid="4" etype="dc" class="remove-absolute" style="display: block"...  Thanks! @VaradMondkar