# How can I remove an H1 with a class assignment?

Tags: html, css, jscript

I have a WordPress site that is using a theme to create some pages. Unfortunately, its creating an H1 in a location I cant edit (only the text, "Home" in this case) and I would like to add my own H1 in another text block location. I'd like to programmatically remove the first H1 and I can do this for H1s (sample page I built by changing it to "body") with this code. (I set i to 0 to only replace the first instance):

```
<script>
    const hTwos = document.querySelectorAll('h1');
    for (let i = 0; i < hTwos.length; i++) {
       hTwos[0].outerHTML = hTwos[i].outerHTML.replace(/h1/g,"body");
    };
</script>
```

However, when there is a class assigned to the H1 the code does not remove it? Is there a way to remove the HTML code for `<h1 class="header-section__title">Home</h1>` from the page using jscript?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the first one then use `classList` for remove class and `textContent` for change text like:

```js
const firstH1 = document.querySelectorAll('h1')[0];
firstH1.classList.remove('header-section__title');
firstH1.textContent = 'My edited title';
```

```html
<h1 class='header-section__title'>Test 1</h1>
<h1>Test 2</h1>
<h1>Test 3</h1>
```

Reference:

- [Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)
- [Node.textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)

Comment: Thanks guys, very imaginative and it seems to have the desired result on page. Now I can add my own H1. Just one related question. When I review the page using the chrome developer tools to search for the H1 or class, I still see multiple H1s in the page code, so the script is running after the page load and rewriting that one element? Is there a way to remove it so SEO doesnt "see" multiple H1s? Thanks!

Comment: Seems like new question :) please acept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [the `remove` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/remove) to remove an element from the DOM.

There's also no point using [the `querySelectorAll` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and looping over the results if you're only going to act on the first result. Just use [the `querySelector` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), which only returns the first result.

```javascript
const h1 = document.querySelector('h1');
if (h1) { h1.remove(); }
```

**NB:** This will completely remove the element and its content from the DOM. If you just want to change it to a different tag, you would need to [replace the element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/replaceChild), as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13389835/124386):

```javascript
const h1 = document.querySelector('h1');
const newEl = document.createElement('div');
newEl.innerHTML = h1.innerHTML;
h1.parentNode.replaceChild(newEl, h1);
```